# asp.net on mono: how to add a reference to an assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, mono

Very basic question - but I couldn't find an answer. 
I have got a asp.net web service which is located in an asmx file. This should call a function from a helper library.
Using a different asmx file in Visual Studio everything is working fine - I just had to add the assembly to the dependencies of this project.

Altough I have copied the assembly to the bin subdirectory on the webserver (I think this was what the descriptions I've read said) it returns this error message:

> Server Error in '/' Application
>   CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   `XXXFunctions' could not be found. Are
>   you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?
>
> Description: HTTP 500. Error
>   processing request.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> System.Web.Compilation.CompilationException:
>   CS0246: The type or namespace name
>   `XXXFunctions' could not be found. Are
>   you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath,
>   System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters
>   options) [0x00000]    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.BuildAssembly
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath)
>   [0x00000]    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly
>   (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder
>   abuilder,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1
>   buildItems, System.Web.VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, BuildKind buildKind)
>   [0x00000]    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BuildAssembly
>   (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath)
>   [0x00000]    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType
>   (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] 
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory.GetHandler
>   (System.Web.HttpContext context,
>   System.String verb, System.String url,
>   System.String filePath) [0x00000]
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory.GetHandler
>   (System.Web.HttpContext context,
>   System.String requestType,
>   System.String url, System.String
>   pathTranslated) [0x00000]    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler
>   (System.Web.HttpContext context,
>   System.String url, Boolean
>   ignoreContextHandler) [0x00000]    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.GetHandler
>   (System.Web.HttpContext context,
>   System.String url) [0x00000]    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication+c__Iterator2.MoveNext
>   () [0x00000]

This is the asmx file I'm using:

```
<%@ Assembly name="System.Web.Extensions" %>
<%@ Assembly name="System.Runtime.Serialization" %>
<%@ Assembly name="System.ServiceModel.Web" %>
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="FCWService.FCWService" %>

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace FCWService
{
    [WebService (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/NumberService")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class FCWService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public XXXFunctions.Data GetData(double length)
        {
            return XXXFunctions.Functions.GetData(length);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas ?

---

Answered:
I found out that there was a <%@ Assembly name="XXXFunctions" %> directive was missing on top the asmx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered: I found out that there was a <%@ Assembly name="XXXFunctions" %> directive was missing on top the asmx page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you copied everything you needed?  There seems to be a namespace or something called XXXFunctions that's missing on the server.

Comment: do I have to restart the server after adding additional binaries in the bin subdirectory - it looks for me he isn't including the files to search for this namespace